# Make <a> anchor tag fill list <li> with display: table-cell

Tags: html, css, html-lists, anchor, href

So here is my issue, I am trying to make the whole list element click able, but for some reason with display: table-cell there is a margin/border either side of the anchor tag, so it does not fill the entire width of the list element.

I want to use display:table-cell so my fit evenly across the navbar.

HTML:

```html
 <ul id="nav_list">
     <li class="selected"><a href="search" id="menu_item" >Search</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="suggest" id="menu_item" >Suggest</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="report" id="menu_item" >Report Bug</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="about" id="menu_item" >About</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="help" id="menu_item" >Help</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```css
#container{
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 500px; 
}
nav ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 background-color:#415d79;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height:auto;
 width: 100%;
 display: table;
 overflow:hidden;
}
nav li{
    display: table-cell;
 padding: 10px;
 color:#FFF;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: 500;
 border-right: 2px solid #364F69;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #324961;
}
nav a{
 padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Remove `li` padding and increase the `li a` padding to sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kk9qqq2f/

I have modified your code a bit to make the entire area of the cell click-able

**CSS**

```
nav li{
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0; /* Changed padding from 10px to 0 */
    color:#FFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-right: 2px solid #364F69;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #324961;
}
nav a{
    padding: 10px;
    display:block; /* Added */
}
```

Comment: Cheers! I thought I had tried everything. Thanks :)

Comment: Adding `display:block` to the anchor tag and removing `padding` on the list item worked for me too. Thanks.

Comment: @Fletch happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
nav a {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

> Use the above CSS

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7bhgvfw1/1/)